# Conditional Probability with coins

Tags: probability

[image]

My thought is to find prob that the second coin is a penny and then calculate 1-that probability since any coin other than the penny is worth at least 5 cents.

If I know the first coin was a dime and not replaced, my reasoning was this is now the same as asking the prob of drawing a penny from the jar with 1 less dime ($74$ total coins). Thus, the prob of drawing a penny would be $24/74=.32$.
So, now the prob of the second coin NOT being a penny would be $25/37$ which is not a choice.  Why doesn't this thought process work?

Comment: Just by inspection...all the given answers are much too low.   The answer is obviously greater than $\frac 12$, say.

Comment: I'll bet answer $c.$ is a typo...should read $\frac {25}{37}$, as you say.

Comment: thank you for taking the time to answer.

Comment: The problem is simpler than it seems.  "given that the first coin is a dime" means you can simply delete one of the dimes (leaving 14 dimes).  Then the probability calculation is trivial.

Comment: I agree, typo. 25/37

Answer (score 0):

Given that a dime was removed from the jar, the jar now has 24 pennies, 17 nickels, 14 dimes, 19 quarters.

The probability that a coin drawn from the jar has value at least 5 cents is 1 minus the probability that a coin drawn from the jar has value less than 5 cents (a penny).

$$ P = 1 - \frac{24}{74} = \frac{50}{74} = \frac{25}{37} $$